# How To go Previous page using C# in asp.net that display all previous details

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it Possible to store Previous Page with Gridview data and all other details and can go back and Display All previous Details. I am using following code but Gridview Data lost because of page post back.

```
 ViewState["RefUrl"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

Comment: Viewstate is only for one page/form, You can use session or querystring to use data through one form to another

Answer (score 0):

Just save your datatable in session and use it in another form

`session["Data"]=dt ;`

while retriving data:

```
DataTable table = Session["Data"] as DataTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Used This. we doesn't loose data of previous page data.

if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            btnBack.PostBackUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
         }